# Multiple panels

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm having two problems with my program. The code below generates two panels when it should generate 3. It generates `panel1` and `panel2` no problem but `panel3` should be to the right of `panel2` is no where to be seen. `Panel1` and `panel2` are split vertically I'm trying to do the same with `panel2` and `panel3`

My second problem is how do I generate another panel below `panel1` without disrupting the splitter between `panel1` and `panel2` and then create a splitter between `panel1` and new created panel below it?

```
import wx


class Panels(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title)

        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self, -1)

        vbox1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        panel1 = wx.Panel(splitter, -1)
        panel12 = wx.Panel(panel1, -1, style=wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)
        st1 = wx.StaticText(panel12, -1, 'Panel 1', (5, 5))
        vbox1.Add(panel12, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        panel1.SetSizer(vbox1)

        vbox2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        panel2 = wx.Panel(splitter, -1)
        panel22 = wx.Panel(panel2, -1, style=wx.BORDER_RAISED)
        st2 = wx.StaticText(panel22, -1, 'Panel 2', (5, 5))
        vbox2.Add(panel22, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        panel2.SetSizer(vbox2)

        vbox3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        panel3 = wx.Panel(splitter, -1)
        panel32 = wx.Panel(panel3, -1, style=wx.BORDER_RAISED)
        st3 = wx.StaticText(panel32, -1, 'Panel 3', (5, 5))
        vbox3.Add(panel32, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        panel3.SetSizer(vbox3)

        hbox.Add(splitter, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.TOP | wx.BOTTOM, 5)
        self.SetSizer(hbox)
        self.CreateStatusBar()
        splitter.SplitVertically(panel1, panel3)
        splitter.SplitVertically(panel2, panel3)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)


    def ExitApp(self, event):
        self.Close()


app = wx.App()
Panels(None, -1, 'Panels')
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a couple options. You could nest your SplitterWindows, which is kind of confusing, but effective. Or you could use the MultiSplitterWindow widget.

For the first one, I'd do something like this:

1. Create a main splitter and a sub-splitter
2. In the sub-splitter, but the first two panels
3. Put the sub-splitter and the 3rd panel in the main splitter

Or some variation thereof.

EDIT: Here's one example:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class RandomPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent, color):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour(color)



########################################################################
class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        topSplitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
        hSplitter = wx.SplitterWindow(topSplitter)

        panelOne = RandomPanel(hSplitter, "blue")
        panelTwo = RandomPanel(hSplitter, "red")
        hSplitter.SplitVertically(panelOne, panelTwo)
        hSplitter.SetSashGravity(0.5)

        panelThree = RandomPanel(topSplitter, "green")
        topSplitter.SplitHorizontally(hSplitter, panelThree)
        topSplitter.SetSashGravity(0.5)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(topSplitter, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

########################################################################
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Nested Splitters",
                          size=(800,600))
        panel = MainPanel(self)
        self.Show()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

See also might want to look at wx.SashLayoutWindow: http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.SashLayoutWindow-class.html

Comment: Could you give me an example of a nested splitter?

Comment: I added an example, although I think you should have tried giving it a go.

Comment: @MikeDriscoll, I deleted my answer as yours is much better. My link to wx.SashLayoutWindow is however gone. Maybe you want to include that possibility for a more complete answer.

Comment: MultiSplitterWindow! This saved my sanity.

Comment: Yup, it's pretty handy!

Comment: Unfortunately, it's kind of... [strange](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818940/constrain-wxpython-multisplitterwindow-panes) in some of its behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1:
Create a horzontal vbox sizer.  Add the sizers for panel2 and panel3 to that.  This will put the panel2 and panel3 next to each other.  Then add the horizontal sizer to the splitter as the second item.

Problem 2:
Create another splitter and add to a sizer (I assume splitter is a widget like panel).  Then create your other panel and add it to that splitter.  So you end up nesting the splitter inside a sizer.  (May not need sizer for that though.)  Then that sizer is inside the main splitter.  You may be able to add the second splitter inside the first.