# Constrain wxPython MultiSplitterWindow panes

Tags: python, layout, wxpython

**Edit:** I'm leaving the question open as is, as it's still a good question and the answer may be useful to others. However, I'll note that I found an actual solution to *my* issue by using a completely different approach with `AuiManager`; see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17837040/564181) below.

I'm working on a `MultiSplitterWindow` setup (after spending a good deal of time
struggling against `SashLayoutWindow` layout quirks). Unfortunately, when I
create a `MultiSplitterWindow`, I see some unexpected behavior when dragging the
sashes around: the sashes can be dragged outside the containing window in the
direction of the layout. To say the least, this is behavior I'd like to avoid.

Here is the basic setup (you can confirm the behavior below in the wxPython
demo, just substituting `leftwin` for `Panel1`, etc., also see below for an example app). Where I have `RootPanel/BoxSizer`, there is a panel
(or `Frame`, or whatever kind of container element you like) with a `BoxSizer`
to which the `MultiSplitterWindow` is added – again, as in demo.

```
+--------------------------------+
|       RootPanel/BoxSizer       |
|+------------------------------+|
||     MultiSplitterWindow      ||
||+--------++--------++--------+||
||| Panel1 || Panel2 || Panel3 |||
|||        ||        ||        |||
||+--------++--------++--------+||
|+------------------------------+|
+--------------------------------+
```

When you drag, you can end up with something like this, where `~` and `!`
indicate that the panel "exists" there but isn't being displayed:

```
+--------------------------------+
|       RootPanel/BoxSizer       |
|+-------------------------------|~~~~~~~~~~~~~+
||           MultiSplitterWindow |             !
||+-----------------++-----------|~~++~~~~~~~~+!
|||      Panel1     ||   Panel2  |  !! Panel3 !!
|||                 ||           |  !!        !!
||+-----------------++-----------|~~++~~~~~~~~+!
|+-------------------------------|~~~~~~~~~~~~~+
+--------------------------------+
```

If at this point, you drag the `RootPanel` to be wider than the
overall set of panels, you will see all the panels again. Likewise, if you drag
the width back down on `Panel1`, you can get access to the sash for `Panel3`
again (assuming the `Panel2` isn't already too wide, of course). Moreover, this
is precisely the situation reported by the Inspection Tool: the `RootPanel`
retains its size, but the `MultiSplitterWindow` grows beyond the size of the
`RootPanel/BoxSizer`.

Further examination with the Inspection Tool reveals that the virtual and client width values are both 0, but the actual size value is *negative* (by the corresponding number of pixels it was dragged out of the window) whenever it's out of range. Again, this is nutty behavior; I can't imagine why one would *ever* want a window to behave this way.

Now, if one holds down `Shift` so that the `_OnMouse` method in
`MultiSplitterWindow` adjusts neighbors, this doesn't happen. Thus, one of my
approaches was to simply override that method. It works, but I'd prefer to
override methods that way if absolutely necessary. Is there another, better way
to solve this problem? It doesn't seem like this would be expected or desirable
behavior in general, so I imagine there is a standard way of fixing it.

### Other things I've tried:

- Checking whether the sum of the values in the `MultiWindowSplitter` exceeds
  the width of the containing window, using each of the
  `EVT_SPLITTER_SASH_POS_CHANGED` AND `EVT_SPLITTER_SASH_POS_CHANGING` events,
  and then trying to fix the issue by:

  - Using an `event.Veto()` call
  - Using the `SetSashPosition()` method on the splitter
- Overriding the `_OnMouse()` method to use the behavior that is normally
  associated with holding down the `Shift` key. This works, but it ends up
  giving me other results I don't like.
- Setting the minimum pane sizes via `SetMinimumPaneSize` method
- Setting the maximum size on `MultiSplitterWindow` via `SetMaxSize()`
- Setting the maximum size on `RootPanel/BoxSizer` using both `SetMaxSize()` and `SetSizeHints()` on the `RootPanel`.

  - I've even done this with an event handler for `wx.EVT_SIZE` on the container so that the `RootPanel` *always* has the appropriate maximum size from the parent frame element
  - I've attempted the same event handling approach for the `MultiSplitterWindow`, also to no effect.

### Version info

I have confirmed that this appears in Windows 32-bit and OS X 64-bit, with the
latest snapshot build of wxPython, against both Python 2.7 and 3.3.

### Working example (with Inspection tool included)

The following essentially duplicates (and slightly simplifies) the demo source. It's a working demonstration of the problem.

```
import wx, wx.adv
import wx.lib.mixins.inspection as wit
from wx.lib.splitter import MultiSplitterWindow


class AppWInspection(wx.App, wit.InspectionMixin):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.Init()  # enable Inspection tool
        return True


class MultiSplitterFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(size=(800, 800), *args, **kwargs)
        self.SetMinSize((600, 600))

        self.top_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(orient=wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.SetSizer(self.top_sizer)

        self.splitter = MultiSplitterWindow(parent=self, style=wx.SP_LIVE_UPDATE)
        self.top_sizer.Add(self.splitter, wx.SizerFlags().Expand().Proportion(1).Border(wx.ALL, 10))

        inner_panel1 = wx.Panel(parent=self.splitter)
        inner_panel1.SetBackgroundColour('#999980')
        inner_panel1_text = wx.StaticText(inner_panel1, -1, 'Inner Panel 1')
        inner_panel1.SetMinSize((100, -1))

        inner_panel2 = wx.Panel(parent=self.splitter)
        inner_panel2.SetBackgroundColour('#999990')
        inner_panel2_text = wx.StaticText(inner_panel2, -1, 'Inner Panel 2')
        inner_panel2.SetMinSize((100, -1))
        inner_panel2.SetMaxSize((100, -1))

        inner_panel3 = wx.Panel(parent=self.splitter)
        inner_panel3.SetBackgroundColour('#9999A0')
        inner_panel3_text = wx.StaticText(inner_panel3, -1, 'Inner Panel 3')
        inner_panel3.SetMinSize((100, -1))

        self.splitter.AppendWindow(inner_panel1)
        self.splitter.AppendWindow(inner_panel2)
        self.splitter.AppendWindow(inner_panel3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = AppWInspection(0)
    frame = MultiSplitterFrame(parent=None, title='MultiSplitterFrame Test')
    app.SetTopWindow(frame)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: post a small example code that demonstrates the problem ... the explanation is good, but seeing implementation will help get you an answer

Comment: @JoranBeasley As noted in the explanation, the best place for anyone to look is in the [wxPython demo](http://wiki.wxpython.org/How%20to%20Learn%20wxPython#Read_the_demo_files). I can duplicate that if you think it's actually useful, though.

Comment: i see ... yeah thats weird ... sorry :/ you can bind a size event listener to the parent and onsize check the boundaries and update them ... but yeah kind of a pain

Comment: Yeah, I've thought of doing that. At that point, you don't have much gain over just using a set of `SashLayoutWindow` components, though (other than a little bit simpler initial layout), and a few things that are potentially weirder because you have default behaviors to override.

Comment: layouts with wx are just a pain I tend to use 5 billion box sizers for everything :/

Comment: Layouts really aren't that bad. You just have to plan out your applications ahead of time. I usually sketch out mine and draw boxes to get an idea of what needs to go where. Then I can decide if I just want nested BoxSizers (usually) or a mix of nested BoxSizers and other sizers.

Comment: @MikeDriscoll, that's exactly the approach I've taken—it's basically the same approach I take with web design, just modified to take into account the different tools available.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what one needs this for, one possible option to use instead of a custom-managed `MultiSplitterWindow` (or `SashLayoutWindow` combinations, etc.) is the Advanced User Interface kit's `AuiManager` tool (documentation for pre-Phoenix version [here](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.aui.AuiManager-class.html); Phoenix docs [here](http://www.wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.agw.html#module-lib.agw)). `AuiManager` automates a lot of these kinds of things for you. In my case, I was attempting to use the `MultiSplitterWindow` as a way of controlling collapsible and resizable panels for the UI in question, so the `AuiManager` is a perfect fit: it already has all the controls and constraints I need built in.

In that case, all one needs to do is create an `AuiManager` instance

(I'm leaving this here as *an* answer in hopes that others who may be taking the same naive approach I was taking will find it useful, but not selecting it as the answer because it does *not* directly answer the original question.)

### Sample use of AUI under Phoenix

This code sample does exactly what I was trying to do with the `MultiSplitterWindow`, but managed automatically by the `AuiManager`.

```
import wx, wx.adv
import wx.lib.mixins.inspection as wit
from wx.lib.agw import aui


class AppWInspection(wx.App, wit.InspectionMixin):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.Init()  # enable Inspection tool
        return True


class AuiFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(size=(800, 800), *args, **kwargs)
        self.SetMinSize((600, 600))

        # Create an AUI Manager and tell it to manage this Frame
        self._manager = aui.AuiManager()
        self._manager.SetManagedWindow(self)

        inner_panel1 = wx.Panel(parent=self)
        inner_panel1.SetBackgroundColour('#999980')
        inner_panel1.SetMinSize((100, 100))
        inner_panel1_info = aui.AuiPaneInfo().Name('inner_panel1').Caption('Inner Panel 1').Left().\
            CloseButton(True).MaximizeButton(True).MinimizeButton(True).Show().Floatable(True)

        inner_panel2 = wx.Panel(parent=self)
        inner_panel2.SetBackgroundColour('#999990')
        inner_panel2_info = aui.AuiPaneInfo().Name('inner_panel2').Caption('Inner Panel 2').Left().Row(1).\
            Show().Floatable(False)

        inner_panel3 = wx.Panel(parent=self)
        inner_panel3.SetBackgroundColour('#9999A0')
        inner_panel3.SetMinSize((100, 100))
        inner_panel3_info = aui.AuiPaneInfo().Name('inner_panel3').Caption('Inner Panel 3').CenterPane()

        self._manager.AddPane(inner_panel1, inner_panel1_info)
        self._manager.AddPane(inner_panel2, inner_panel2_info)
        self._manager.AddPane(inner_panel3, inner_panel3_info)
        self._manager.Update()

    def __OnQuit(self, event):
        self.manager.UnInit()
        del self.manager
        self.Destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = AppWInspection(0)
    frame = AuiFrame(parent=None, title='AUI Manager Test')
    app.SetTopWindow(frame)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try setting the panel's MaxSize or even resort to SetSizeHints(). Both of these allow you to set some constraints on the size of the widget.

Comment: I actually thought I had tried that, but I'll give it a go and see.

Comment: Okay, so, after some further testing: (1) neither `SetMaxSize()` nor `SetSizeHints()` has any effect. Moreover, further investigation with the inspection tool indicates that the offscreen panels have zero virtual or client width, but an *actual* width with *negative* values. There has *got* to be a way to disallow this behavior; I can't think of why you would ever *want* it. Note that I'm adding this info to the question as well.

Comment: I linked to your question from the wxPython mailing list since I'm not sure what's going on here.

Comment: Thanks. I've subscribed to that topic, so I should see any updates that come in there.